# Which SDK do I need to start using sharepoint.client.dll?

Tags: sharepoint, sdk, client, service

I want to test drive Microsoft.SharePoint.Client API.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.aspx

How can I get Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll?

The 'SharePoint 2010 Reference: Software Development Kit' has samples.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=f0c9daf3-4c54-45ed-9bde-7b4d83a8f26f

Is there an SDK that has the dll?

Answer (score 21):

This blog annouces a 466K redist.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/11/18/sharepoint-client-object-model-redistributable-released.aspx

The 'SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable' is here.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b4579045-b183-4ed4-bf61-dc2f0deabe47

contains

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Answer (score 12):

For me these files lived in:

**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client**

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll
```

other have reported them being in:
**%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI**

which did not exist for me.

Comment: For me, the 2010 versions were located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client and the 2013 versions installed to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI

Comment: For me, found at:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI

Answer (score 0):

Path in SharePoint server(System where it is installed) :
**

### C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client

**
You can download it from below link:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Sites-Core/tree/master/Assemblies/15

Nuget Package :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll/

Cheers

Comment: Those are for SP 2013, not SP 2010.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK kit

Installed at:  **C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI**