# Vsto Word: After install, error: could not load assembly

Tags: c#, vsto

I've made a vsto for word, that uses the dll : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll. The vsto runs perfect on my (dev) machine and then VS2013/rigtclick/properties/publish.

For the user's PC (Xp + office 2010, install the app) I get the error:  could not load assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll.
How can I solve/bypass this error?

Thank you

p.S.This is my first VSTO, so newbie errors are highly propable

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the client computer doesn't have the correct libraries installed.  I doubt that having Office 2010 installed will give you the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime dll.

You'll probably need the 'SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable' installed on the client machine.

From the most voted answer in this thread:
[Which SDK do I need to start using sharepoint.client.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961622/which-sdk-do-i-need-to-start-using-sharepoint-client-dll)